# User: hadoop is not allowed to impersonate xfvm

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

hdfs： use webhdfs  this question：

through Browser request url：
http://192.168.56.11:14000/webhdfs/v1/user?op=LISTSTATUS

but response text is：
{"RemoteException":{"message":"User: hadoop is not allowed to impersonate xfvm","exception":"RemoteException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException"}}

why？

Comment: Did you start hadoop as the xfvm user? If so, by default only that user can read the files

Comment: Do you have HttpFS working correctly and you just have an issue with this user or are you trying to get HttpFS working?

Comment: Edit your question and include these two files: httpfs-site.xml and core-site.xml (just the parts related to HttpFS)